# How to make elements count differently on Counter with javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a counter which I made with Javascript, I want to add a function or anything else to delay the count at some elements so that they count on with the same speed. here is an example on this website https://www.ifunds-germany.de/ => standorte starts to count late.

```js
let counter = document.getElementById('counter');
window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
    // This is then function used to detect if the element is scrolled into view
    function isScrolledIntoView(el) {
        var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
        var elemTop = rect.top;
        var elemBottom = rect.bottom;

        // Only completely visible elements return true:
        var isVisible = (elemTop >= 0) && (elemBottom <= window.innerHeight);
        // Partially visible elements return true:
        //isVisible = elemTop < window.innerHeight && elemBottom >= 0;
        return isVisible;
    }

    // This is where we use the function to detect if ".box2" is scrolled into view, and when it is add the class ".animated" to the <p> child element
    if (isScrolledIntoView(counter)) {
        const counters = document.querySelectorAll(".counter");
        const speed = 200;

        counters.forEach(counter => {
            const updateCount = () => {
                const target = +counter.getAttribute('data-target');
                const count = +counter.innerText;
                const inc = target / speed;

                if (count < target) {
                    counter.innerText = Math.ceil(count + inc);
                    setTimeout(updateCount, 1);
                } else {
                    count.innerText = target;
                }
            }

            updateCount();
        });
    }
});
```

```html
 <div id="counter">
        <div class="g-grid counters" style="justify-content: space-between;">
            <div class="g-block size-20 g-infolist-item-white-background">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-calendar-plus fa-5x"></i>
                <div class="counter" data-target="15">0</div>
                <h2 class="g-main-feature-title">Jahre Erfahrung</h2>
            </div>

            <div class="g-block size-20 g-infolist-item-white-background">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-list-check fa-5x"></i>
                <div class="counter" data-target="150">0</div>
                <h2 class="g-main-feature-title">erfolgreiche Projekte</h2>
            </div>

            <div class="g-block size-20 g-infolist-item-white-background">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-code fa-5x"></i>
                <div class="counter" data-target="1000000">0</div>
                <h2 class="g-main-feature-title">Zeilen Code</h2>
            </div>

            <div class="g-block size-20 g-infolist-item-white-background">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-mug-saucer fa-5x"></i>
                <div class="counter" data-target="324000">0</div>
                <h2 class="g-main-feature-title">Tassen Kaffee</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Looks to me like in the given example, they probably simply divided the whole animation duration, by the number of different values - and then adjusted the step length accordingly.

Comment: Did you know you can open the developer tools on other websites? They certainly have code somewhere for that! I would assume what @CBroe suggested.

Comment: yes but it seems like they used some jquery library or something, which I can’t use since my project is pure vanilla JS :(